# how to make console application in cakephp 3.0 with database

Tags: database, cakephp, console-application, cakephp-3.0

I just tried to use CakePHP 3.0 and I want to make a console application. I have a database and I want to showing the data from one table in my database on web console application. Could you help me? What the code that i can use to make the console application? thankyou

Comment: Google it first please

Comment: i can't find the answer. can you give me a solution ?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for *too specific* a term... Could you edit your question with what you have so far?

Comment: Have you read the Docu? What have you tried until now? What were the results? 
Please show some effort, before you ask effort of others.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the official documentation on creating console commands:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells.html